# When does java.lang.EnumConstantNotPresentException gets thrown?

Tags: java, enums, runtimeexception

As per java API EnumConstantNotPresentException gets thrown when an application tries to access an enum constant by name and the enum type contains no constant with the specified name.

Thus I decided to come up with a scenario where java.lang.EnumConstantNotPresentException will be thrown, so I wrote following three classes.

MyEnum class:

```
package my.enumtest;

enum MyEnum {
    A, B, C;
}
```

MyEnumTest1 class:

```
package my.enumtest;

    import my.enumtest.MyEnum;

    class MyEnumTest1 {

        public static void main(String [] args) {
            System.out.println(MyEnum.A);        
        }        
    }
```

MyEnumTest2 class:

```
package my.enumtest;

import my.enumtest.MyEnum;

class MyEnumTest2 {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println(MyEnum.valueOf("A"));        
    }
}
```

I compiled all three and then I changed the MyEnum class to drop constant 'A' and recompiled it:

```
package my.enumtest;

enum MyEnum {
    B, C;
}
```

On execution of MyEnumTest1 with new MyEnum class, I got following exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: A
>           at my.enumtest.MyEnumTest1.main(MyEnumTest1.java:8)

On execution of MyEnumTest2 with new MyEnum class, I got following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum
>   constant my.enumtest.MyEnum.A
>           at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source)
>           at my.enumtest.MyEnum.valueOf(MyEnum.java:3)
>           at my.enumtest.MyEnumTest2.main(MyEnumTest2.java:8)

As you can see in none of the cases I got EnumConstantNotPresentException, so can someone provide me usage of EnumConstantNotPresentException class?

**P.S.** I know that this exception can be thrown by the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html) used to read annotations reflectively but I am looking for more obvious (simpler) scenario.

Comment: This is a link to the EnumConstantNotPresentException class... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/EnumConstantNotPresentException.html . I've got the feeling I'm missing something, the question

Comment: The javadoc (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/EnumConstantNotPresentException.html) says: * This exception can be thrown by the API used to read annotations reflectively.*, and contains a link pointing to the class describing when the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you should do if you want to know when the specific exception is thrown is to read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/EnumConstantNotPresentException.html) as JB Nizet mentioned. It says:

> Thrown when an application tries to access an enum constant by name and the enum type contains no constant with the specified name. This exception can be thrown by the [API used to read annotations reflectively](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html).

The link follows to `AnnotationElement` which documentation says:

> Similarly, attempting to read an enum-valued member will result in a `EnumConstantNotPresentException` if the enum constant in the annotation is no longer present in the enum type.

This is enough to craft an example.
Create the following classes:

```
// TestEnum.java
public enum TestEnum {
    A, B, C;
}

// TestAnnotation.java
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TestAnnotation {
    TestEnum value();
}

// TestClass.java
@TestAnnotation(TestEnum.C)
public class TestClass {

}

// ReadAnnotation.java
public class ReadAnnotation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(TestClass.class.getAnnotation(TestAnnotation.class).value());
    }
}
```

Compile everything and run `ReadAnnotation`. You will got `C`.

Now remove the `C` from the `TestEnum` and recompile only `TestEnum` class preserving other classes as is. If you launch `ReadAnnotation` now, you will get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.EnumConstantNotPresentException: TestEnum.C
    at sun.reflect.annotation.EnumConstantNotPresentExceptionProxy.generateException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.value(Unknown Source)
    at ReadAnnotation.main(ReadAnnotation.java:4)
```

If you wonder whether it can be thrown by anything else, you may scan the JDK sources for this exception name. I did not found any other mentions of this exception, so seems that reflection is the only possible case.

Comment: This is a good example but I think it would be a better answer if you included an explanation of why this triggers the `EnumConstantNotPresentException` and why sactiw's examples do not.

Comment: @Tagir +1 for your reply but in my question I already have a footnote mentioning that _they can be thrown by the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html#getAnnotation(java.lang.Class)) used to read annotations reflectively but I am looking for more obvious (simpler) scenario._ Basically can they be thrown in any other scenario?

Comment: @sactiw, check the note at the very end of my reply.

Comment: @Tagir Yes I understand your point and I already did the same and didn't come across any usage. But then the API **doesn't** says that "This exception can be **ONLY** be thrown by the API used to read annotations reflectively" Right?

Comment: @sactiw, such remark would limit JDK developers from further extensions of this exception usage. So currently it's used only for reflection, but developers are free to add more usage patterns in future.

Comment: Yes and thus I was expecting to see more than one example. At least a simpler one that doesn't comes from sun.* packages which are specific to Oracle jdk and may change in future releases. :)

Answer (score 0):

An enum in java is often also called *synthetic sugar*. **What is meant with that?**

Enum constants are converted to public static final MyEnum fields with the name of the enum constant and the value of the constructor of the class at compile-time. 
That means by accessing MyEnum.MY_CONSTANT, you access the **field**:

```
public static final MyEnum MY_CONSTANT = new MyEnum();
```

Since the reflection API now also provides methods for examining enum constants (See Enamiming Enums in the Guide) via `getEnumConstants()` and `isEnumConstant()`, java has a way to tell which field was an enum constant and which field wasn't. So these fields aren't quite as plain as youd'd think after the first paragraph.

The NoSuchFieldException is thrown because... well there is no such field created by the respective enum.

The IllegalArgumentException is thrown by the reflection API as it is an Exception designed for that API and for example `Enum#valueOf()`. That method uses reflection to find the given enum constant by name (string).

Comment: Not sure if you read the question throoughly because the the 3rd class in the example makes use of valueOf() method and as expected it throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant` and not EnumConstantNotPresentException.

Comment: Indeed, I misread the actual question in the original post. My answer just explaines some differences regarding enums and doesn't answer your question.